# Flutter: 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: json, flutter, rest, dio

**I am currently building an app to read data through an api and I am trying to parse a JSON api from JSON Placeholder.**

Unhandled Exception: type List <dynamic is not a subtype of type 'String'

This is http class

```
class HttpService {
  final url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums";
  late Dio _dio;

  HttpService(){
    _dio = Dio();
  }
  
  Future<UserModel> fetchData() async {
    var response = await _dio.get(url);

      return UserModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.data));
    
  }
}
```

This is a model class

```
class UserModel {
  UserModel({
    required this.userId,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });

  int userId;
  int id;
  String title;

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
        userId: json["userId"],
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
      );
}
```

This is a home screen

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Http Requests"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<UserModel>(
        future: HttpService().fetchData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            return Text(snapshot.data!.title);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Error I'm getting is

> Unhandled Exception: type List <dynamic is not a subtype of type 'String'>

Comment: What is `response.data` value?

Comment: data we get from http

Comment: can show the json response?

Comment: [{userId: 1, id: 1, title: quidem molestiae enim}, {userId: 1, id: 2, title: sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa}, {userId: 1, id: 3, title: omnis laborum odio}, {userId: 2, id: 15, title: ut pariatur rerum ipsum natus repellendus praesentium}, {userId: 2, id: 16, title: voluptatem aut maxime inventore autem magnam atque repellat}]

Comment: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums

Comment: U are getting a list of elements from the api and you are trying to pass title to Text widget without selecting an individual element of the list? Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your response data is a List. You can't return it as Object.

The correct way should be

```
Future<List<UserModel>> fetchData() async {
    var response = await _dio.get(url);
    Iterable l = json.decode(response.body);
    return  List<UserModel>.from(l.map((model)=> 
    UserModel.fromJson(model)));  
  }
```

Same changes for `FutureBuilder`.

```
FutureBuilder<List<UserModel>>
```

You may use `ListView` widget to display it.